# changing schemas in hive from command line

Tags: hive

How to change hive schema from command line?

I need to run `hql` scripts for creating tables but those tables need to be created inside a particular schema.

I am using **hive -f createTable.hql** to create table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter(s) to the script:

```
hive -hiveconf myschema=newschema -f createTable.hql
```

Then in the script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${hiveconf:myschema}
LOCATION "/foo/dir";

USE ${hiveconf:myschema};
```

Any tables you then create will be in that working schema. You can also make the variables part of the name:

```
hive -hiveconf name=Bob -f createTable.hql
```

In the script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${hiveconf:name}_SCHEMA
LOCATION "/foo/dir";

USE ${hiveconf:name}_SCHEMA;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that inside your hql/ddl statement.

```
USE schemaName;

create table.....
....
```

So, basically you can tell hive to use a specific schema by  using the "USE" statement.
You can also write it in hive CLI.

Comment: the problem is that there are 600+ create table scripts and so I will need to add USE statement in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run queries in a particular schema via command line you can use the below command:

```
hive -e "use schema_name; show tables;"
```

but -f and -e cannot be used both in same command.